# How does Cypress handle server-side authentication during a click event?

Tags: cypress, ibm-cloud, navigator

[image: Code Execution]

I'm working on a POC using Cypress to automate the web version of IBM Navigator for i. However, an ERROR is encountered when the script attempts to click certain (but not all) links. I believe that the error is generated since Cypress is running in the browser and the AS400 backend is expecting some additional authentication to be passed with the click. Please see the attached .GIF as an example. Note the ERROR presented at the end. The issue is NOT present when same functionality executed manually or using UFT or node.js via Protractor. Below is a screenshot of successful navigation.

Here are the steps performed by the Cypress script:

1. Launch IBM Navigator for i in Chrome
2. Perform a login
3. Navigate to the 5250 Emulation screen/tab by expanding/clicking the necessary branches

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect browser console in DevTools or the network tab?

Comment: I have but (admittedly) I'm uncertain what to look for.

Comment: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for http://hqd400:2004/__cypress/runner/popper.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
cypress_runner.js:190956 Console was cleared
VM19351 logon.jsp:234 The protocol is http:
dojo.js:1862 Error: defineAlreadyDefined
    at makeError (dojo.js:119:15)
    at dojo.js:1911:18
    at dojo.js:1941:1
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:1862
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:345
forEach @ dojo.js:106
req.signal @ dojo.js:344
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:1911
(anonymous) @ dojo.js:1941
dojo.js:1865 src: dojoLoader

Comment: I would compare the network calls in the network tab when performing the tasks manually, versus when Cypress does performs them and see if there are any differences. I would be looking for calls failing with 400 or 500 HTTP error statuses and debug from there.

Have you tried running in different browsers? Cypress supports both Firefox and Chrome. 

With that said, there are apps that do not work well with Cypress due to the way it loads the application and interacts with it. I found older apps may have more issues than newer ones.

Comment: I would also look at different Cypress config options and seeing if any of them might related. I would start with these ones.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Browser

Hopefully these tips can help

Comment: Thanks DJSDev - I'll have a look

Comment: The same error occurs across all browsers.  I'm researching network calls now.